# iPad Offline Web App with Multiple Entries

Tags: ios, html, ipad, local-storage

I've found a ton of information on LocalStorage with HTML5 but they all focus on persistent single entries being saved.

I need to be able to have a contact form (simple name/email/phone) that gets saved to the iPad and then allows another person to submit an entry to save to the iPad locally (no Wifi/Internet available).

Then I want to be able to go in later and grab all the entries that were made in whatever format available.

Any direction & help would be appreciated.

I searched on Stackoverflow & Google but still couldn't find multiple entry tutorials or examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your question isn't a good fit for the format here -- you've asked a pretty general question and it's hard to see what if anything you've already done to try to answer the question on your own. Questions that ask for very general guidance without supplying clarifying details don't tend to get good answers here.

Comment: Sorry about that Scott! I guess my issue is that I've been searching and not coming up with any results on how to even start with multiple entries in an offline environment using HTML5 and either LocalStorage or some other alternative. If I had a starting point to play with then i could provide more info, but I'm stuck finding a starting point. But I fully understand...hopefully will find something and then refine my question I guess. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage` is a good fit for what you're after. As `localStorage` only supports strings, you will need to do some conversions to/from JSON to serialize the entries.

Here is some general code to hopefully get you started:

```
// read out any previous contact forms (initialise if it is empty)
var jsonEntries = localStorage["contactFormEntries"];
var contactFormEntries = JSON.parse(jsonEntries ? jsonEntries : '[]');

// ...

// sometime later... create a contact form record
var contactForm = {
    'name': 'Timmy',
    'email': 'timmy@example.com'
};

// add it to the entries array
contactFormEntries.push(contactForm);

// serialize all the contact form entries into local storage
localStorage["contactFormEntries"] = JSON.stringify(contactFormEntries);

// ...

// then, when you want to send the entries, read them all out again
var contactFormEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage["contactFormEntries"]);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you...this gives me a good starting point now!